# Interpolating Points on a Raster when Resampling

Tags: qgis, gdal

I have a coarse GeoTiff at 1km that I want to resample down (let's say 100m for this example).  I resample it using `gdalwarp -tr 100 100 -r bilinear A.tif B.tif`

This works fine, but it doesn't produce any smoothing of the values themselves, only a contouring effect where the original values are maintained.

Is there a way to use gdal tools to interpolate the points that get generated?  So that if two "coarse" pixels are next to each other and have values of 2 and 3, the inbetween values will be a gradient of 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, etc.?

[image: Course Image]
[image: Resampled Image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so it turns out this was far simpler than I had thought. The reason it couldn't properly interpolate was because the input file was an Integer based file, and so it produced the output file that way.

Adding `-ot Float32` allowed GDAL to properly interpolate and produce the in between values for smoothing using the `-r bilinear` flags.

Final result:

[image: Final Smoothed Result]